# Folder showing lock icon in Ubuntu

Tags: icons, directory, lock

I have a folder showing a lock icon. I can't execute any programs that are in this folder.

I have tried to run the commands:

```
chmod 777 folder_name
```

and

```
sudo chown -R USER:HOME folder_name
```

When I do so I get as a response that it is a read-only file system.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Information you gave, it seems the Drive you're trying to read from might be mounted without write or execute access.

To do that you can set that in `gnome-disks` by selecting your drive, selecting the partition you want to mount and clicking on the settings icon. There you can edit the mount options. Uncheck "User Session Defaults" and in the textfield containing `nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show` you simply add `rw,exec` to enable read/write and execution access.